# Debugging: Get content of variables bound inside functions

Tags: javascript

I have some function defined inside a function, but set to global:

```
function someFn(someVar) {
    var arr = makeArray(someVar);
    // global function:
    foo = function(bar) {
        return arr.indexOf(bar)==-1;
    }
}
```

When I debug with chrome console:

```
> foo
function (bar){return arr.indexOf(bar)==-1;}
```

can I get, without changing the source code, the content of `arr`?

Let's assume I can't just get and execute the commands by which `arr` was generated, because I don't know the last value of `someVar`.

The variable has to be somewhere in the memory, because when I call the function, it can be accessed, but what name does it have? I already tried:

```
>  foo.arr
undefined
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint and add a watch on the variable.

Comment: I agree it has to be somewhere in memory, but it's stored under a certain execution context, which makes it more difficult; it's entirely possible 10 functions have called `someFn`, and each is granted a separate instance of `arr`.

Comment: @Katana314 yes, they have, but all but the last one can be GC'ed because they are no longer required anywhere. And then, the function I call knows where to look. I don't know. functions are smarter than me who wrote them back then. Sooo saaad...

Comment: @Nit I should have mentioned all details: It's a minified JS file on a live system. I can't add a breakpoint since the function has no own line. I can't reproduce the issue in our dev environment without knowledge about the contents of `arr`, and I am not allowed to hand out the unminified version to a customer. Security by obscurity, you know...

Comment: First off, security by obscurity in Javascript is no security, since taking apart code is as easy as throwing it in JSBeautifier. Secondly, you can add a breakpoint in a minified file, simply press the `{}` button at the bottom left of the source file in Chrome's inspector to have it automatically format the file for preview. That one button click is exactly how much _"security"_ your minified source gives you.

Comment: I got the impression from the way he wrote "you know" that he's perfectly aware how much security it gives, but is not in charge of that poor decision-making =p

Comment: @Nit "Security by obscurity" *never* gives any security. Your hint as to the  `{}` works wonders. They put so many features into Chrome debugger, one just has to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-Y problem response; I don't know how you could access `arr` from the console, but I can give you a few tips to debugging via a breakpoint, even if the code is minified.

Try using Google Chrome, and in Debugger, click the `{}` icon below the code window. That will pretty-print the script, though the varnames will still be minified. (`_a1 = new`_43` etc.)

Next is the art of reading minified code; Code minifiers can't change anything that is accessed via a string; the most signature of which are object properties (anything after a `.`). It also helps that without whitespace, it becomes easier to find a particular sequence of symbols. You could try CTRL-Fing for terms like `.indexOf`, `==-1`, etc. If this is an actual corporate-released library, chances are you can go beyond your little example and refer to things like `myCompanyLibrary.dockInstance.locator=`.

Once you find that line, you can put a breakpoint there. Good luck!

Comment: Why would you not be able to obscure something that's accessed by a string? That's nonsense. For example, `[1,2,3]['\u0069\u006e\u0064\u0065\u0078\u004f\u0066'](2)` translates to and works identically to `[1,2,3].indexOf(2)`.

Comment: He, and I, never mentioned a code obscurer; in fact I don't think those are used often. A **code minifier** won't do what you just described because it makes the code bigger, not smaller.

Comment: There's a large difference between _can't_ and _won't_.

Comment: Your answer states a minifier **can't** change anything accessed via a string. This is simply not true. The above snippet is just an example that you're not limited to a string literal, you could just as easily write an example that shortens calls.

Comment: As I already said, writing an example which demonstrates that you can shorten away string literals is trivial. Detecting when it's safe to do so is a non-trivial matter which is why most minimizers don't do it by default, but some do with correct flags, as a trade-off of size over speed.